# Embedded sender view with go back to previous page issue on send=0

Tags: docusignapi

I added embedded sender view to my site. If I set default to drag&drop view (send=1), everything is working fine. I can press go back to document view.
After submitting, it will redirect to the return url that I provide.

However, if I set the default to document view (send=0), when I press the go back. I receive a blank page.

[image]

Comment: What is the error message (if any) when you receive the blank page ? (F12 in Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for posting this. I believe this is a bug and should be fixed. we'll update this thread when we have a proper fix in place. thanks!

Comment: the bug will be fixed by the end of the month. Hope that helps